# how can i return a null value if the AND statement produces no results?

Tags: mysql

i have a pretty lengthy sql statement that pulls data based on a users input. one of the parameters is a date range and currently if the date does not exist then nothing is returned. im trying to figure out how to place the AND parameter within an if condition so that if the date does not exist, the data is still returned with a null. i have looked into IFNULL and CASE but cant seem to figure out a way to implement it properly

```
SELECT pName,pNum,pPhase,pStart,pEnd,pComp,pHoursBudgeted,Zee_Kray_A
FROM hourmap 
JOIN projects ON projects.pID = hourmap.ProjectID 
JOIN schedule ON schedule.id = hourmap.ScheduleID 
WHERE (pManager LIKE '%' or pManager is Null) 
AND (pNum LIKE '%90668%' or pNum is Null) 
AND (year_week LIKE '2020-W01'or year_week is Null)
;
```

within the sql above, in the last parameter, if 2020-W01 is anything other than this, than there is nothing returned. how can i place this final parameter in an if statement or make it conditional?

Comment: You probably need a left join in there. Hard to tell where though since there is no way of knowing from the code where year_week lives.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and move the left joined  colunms condition in ON clause

```
SELECT pName,pNum,pPhase,pStart,pEnd,pComp,pHoursBudgeted,Zee_Kray_A
FROM hourmap 
LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.pID = hourmap.ProjectID 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON schedule.id = hourmap.ScheduleID 
AND  (pManager LIKE '%' or pManager is Null) 
AND (pNum LIKE '%90668%' or pNum is Null) 
AND (year_week LIKE '2020-W01'or year_week is Null)
;
```